# Where should I post this question? SO or DBA?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I've got a question about my TVP insert code. I don't know if it's a problem with the SQL I'm using (so DBA because TVP is new and may have other tricks I don't know about) or if it's just bad form on me for my C# (so SO it would be).

I know that we're still trying to keep things on target and which goes where, and I'm torn on this one. I do want to make sure my TSQL is right, but I think that it's fine (cos SSMS accepts it ;] ) but I really think it's my C#.

Since I gotta post both pieces for it to be useful, it's going to boil down to more C# than TSQL I believe. Guidance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd post on SO first, because you're more likely to find someone there who can at least tell you *where* the problem is, if not *what* it is.  At that point, if you decide it *is* a TSQL problem you could post a followup question here.

Comment: Yeah, I think I'm going to do that. I think I also figured out what my bug was on the walk home last night :\ ... debugging this morning.

Comment: It actually ended up being a "go home and sleep on it and debug it in the shower" solution.

Comment: Excellent answer.  I like to see SQL questions here, but as soon as you have to post C# to know where the problem is that definitely tips it in the SO direction.

Comment: @Leigh ~ So my thinking was that TVP's are new to me and to a lot of other devs, so might as well investigate if it was my TVP was done incorrectly, which means SQL only. Just so tricky to know what you don't know, yeah? ;)

Comment: @drachenstern Sure, if you are just posting the SQL then this site is a fine place.  I certainly wouldn't mind a question asking if some SQL was correct.

Comment: Yeah but your other point is the right point there @Leigh ;)