# 2 pivot questions enter, one question leaves

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Do questions on querying belong here?

There were two questions on DBA about using the PIVOT operator in the past 12 hours.

- [why does my pivot give me an error?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6046/why-does-my-pivot-give-me-an-error)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508820/how-do-i-pivot-this-sql-result

The second was punted over to SO while the first remains. It seems that questions about querying a database are valid here and based on the [FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq)

> database professionals who wish to improve their database skills and
>   learn from others in the community

I'd expect admin's to be cognizant of the "new" language features and use them to improve their querying skills but maybe that's a bad assumption.

Related meta questions

- [Should this question have gotten migrated here?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/should-this-question-have-gotten-migrated-here)
- [Are DB questions going to be migrated from SO?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/are-db-questions-going-to-be-migrated-from-so)
- [Where should I post this question? SO or DBA?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/where-should-i-post-this-question-so-or-dba)
- [What kind of questions are allowed on Database Administrators ?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-kind-of-questions-are-allowed-on-database-administrators) (closest to answering with 'addresses Database Queries but indicates "pro" level')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I punted the second one because there is a difference between "how do I" and "what the hell just broke" and honestly, I would have punted the first one had I seen it earlier.

We said during site formation that we wanted "higher level SQL questions" here, but not ones about "basic SQL syntax". To me, asking merely "how do I pivot this" isn't really "dba worthy". If I asked my dba that, she would look at me drolly and ask me to google it. (Rather, I would've googled it myself)

If I said "um, I swear I've got this syntax right, what gives?" she might not see it as so dumb, but still, it's a code question, and not something about the specific internals of the database platform.

Maybe it was a bad call on my part to migrate the one, but I felt it was the right thing to do. I also lobby for other sites to send us database questions, I'm just trying to find the right mix of Q for this site, without taking *every little niggling sql problem* under our belt. Surely you don't write every bit of CRUD that your apps use, and you do trust your programmers to write those for your apps, right?